# Query is working in Mongo but not working with spring-data-mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in mongo which contains 6 documents .When I run query directly in mongo it is qorking fine.But when I run the same query in spring , I am not getting the result

I have the following query

```
 Mongo DB: db.getCollection('table_name').find({"column_1" : "value_1" })
```

Spring :

```
 Query q = new BasicQuery("{ column_1: 'value_1'}");
    this.mongoOps.find(q, TableName.class, "table_name");
```

I tried with different mongo versions ans with different spring versions but not working.What might be the issue here.

**NOTE:Query is working with JDBC as well**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you're using `Mongo`, you should use the correct *Terminology* to describe your problem..I guess you have a *Collection* of 6 *Documents*. And I don't get this part when you say `Query is working with JDBC as well`. JDBC is for relational databases and Mongo is a NoSQL one.

Comment: @AliDehghani Thanks I updated

Comment: @AliDehghani When I run in plain jdbc it is working

Comment: When you say, not working, you mean that you have an Exception raised, or nothing happen ? where are you storing the result here ?

Comment: Just a guess, has something to do with the String and single quotes: Try changing Query q = new BasicQuery("{ column_1: 'value_1'}"); to  Query q = new BasicQuery("{ column_1: value_1}"); 
More info on http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.query

Comment: It is not returning any data

Answer (score 1):

If you're considerating use `Query` class, try adding `Criteria`

```
 Query query = new Query();
 query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("field_1").in("value_1"));
```

**Edit**
If you want to use `BasicQuery`, try:

```
BasicQuery query1 = new BasicQuery("{ 'field': 'value_1' }");
User userTest1 = mongoOperation.findOne(query1, YourClass.class);
```

Remember in Mongo we don't call column to fields, because it doesn't has column :)

Comment: For example only I gave column.I used exactly the field name

Comment: I am not getting any error.Just it is returning empty resultset

Comment: @PSR When you debug you can catch the query and test it in mongo and see the result

Comment: Maybe the mapping between YourClass.class and the document structure (or the object in which you try to store the result) are not compatible...